# After installing upstart Raspberrypi gets stuck in boot

Tags: linux, boot, raspberry-pi, upstart

I recently installed upstart blindly replacing things I shouldn't of been. The results was that now my raspberry pi is stuck on

> Setting up X socket directories... /tmp/.X11-unix /tmp/.ICE-unix

Is there anyway I can fix this without a complete wipe of the OS and starting over? Could I mount card on my laptop (running mint-linux) and repair the files that way or remove upstart?

I've read some [posts](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=26772) on the native forum which don't seem to offer many options.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on my Debian jessie (8.3) after switching from i386 to amd64. The solution was to remove upstart. Luckily I had 0 dependencies on it:

```
sudo aptitude purge upstart
```